# Cucumber - Java - Maven - Extended Reports - Not able to add date to reports

Tags: java, maven, cucumber-junit

I'm trying to make format to my reports adding the timestamp to the generated reports in Cucumber with JUnit in Maven, but I can't reach it.

This is my runner:

```
import com.github.mkolisnyk.cucumber.runner.ExtendedCucumber;
import com.github.mkolisnyk.cucumber.runner.ExtendedCucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(ExtendedCucumber.class)
@ExtendedCucumberOptions(
        jsonReport = "target/cucumber-reports/CucumberTestReport.json",
        retryCount = 3,
        detailedReport = true,
        detailedAggregatedReport = true,
        overviewReport = true,
        coverageReport = true,
        jsonUsageReport = "target/cucumber-reports/cucumber-usage/cucumber-usage.json",
        usageReport = true,
        toPDF = true,
        excludeCoverageTags = {"@flaky" },
        includeCoverageTags = {"@passed" },
        outputFolder = "target/cucumber-reports/extended-report")

@CucumberOptions(
        features =  {"src/test/resource/features"},
        glue=       {"stepdefs"},
        monochrome = true,
        tags =      {"~@Ignore"},
        plugin =    {
                    "pretty", "html:target/cucumber-reports/cucumber-html-report",
                    "json:target/cucumber-reports/CucumberTestReport.json",
                    "usage:target/cucumber-reports/cucumber-usage/cucumber-usage.json",
                    "rerun:target/cucumber-reports/rerun.txt"}
        )

public class TestRunner {

}
```

In the POM file I added the next properties:

```
<properties>
        <cucumber.version>1.2.5</cucumber.version>
        <serenity.version>1.2.5-rc.6</serenity.version>
        <serenity.cucumber.version>1.1.29</serenity.cucumber.version>
        <java.version>8</java.version>
        <timestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</timestamp>
        <maven.build.timestamp.format>dd-MM-yyyy_HHmm</maven.build.timestamp.format>
        <reports.sub.directory>${maven.build.timestamp}</reports.sub.directory>
        <reports.directory>reports/${reports.sub.directory}</reports.directory>
    </properties>
```

The idea is not override the reports generated, but I'm not able to do it.

Could anybody help me with this?